# How can i re-organise this dataframe into this format?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot

my data looks like:

```
shops        spend_y1     atv_y1   asc_y1    spend_y2     atv_y2   asc_y2
company_a    123.4          89        9.4         10        340     56
company_b    13.4           56.3      113        1000       3000   130
```

i want to reorganise it into:

```
  shops           y1     y2   
    company_a
    spend        123.4   10
    atv          89      340
    asc          9.4     56
  
    company_b    
    spend        13.4    1000
    atv          56.3    3000
    asc          113     130
```

how can i do this in pandas? is it possible...

Answer (score 3):

Another solution, with `.melt` and `.pivot`:

```py
df = df.melt(id_vars="shops", var_name=" ")
df[[" ", ""]] = df[" "].str.split("_", expand=True)
print(df.pivot(index=["shops", " "], columns=[""], values="value"))
```

Prints:

```
                    y1      y2
shops                         
company_a asc      9.4    56.0
          atv     89.0   340.0
          spend  123.4    10.0
company_b asc    113.0   130.0
          atv     56.3  3000.0
          spend   13.4  1000.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Set `shops` as index. Now you can split columns into two levels (`MultiIndex`) and stack the first level:

```py
df = df.set_index("shops")
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)  # *
df = df.stack(level=0)
```

```py
                    y1    y2
shops
company_a asc      9.4    56
          atv     89.0   340
          spend  123.4    10
company_b asc    113.0   130
          atv     56.3  3000
          spend   13.4  1000
```

* *Changed from `pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuple(df.columns.str.split('_')))` to `df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)` according to @sammywemmy comment.*

Comment: Pass expand = True to split  to get a MultiIndex, instead of calling pd.Multindex.